# Protect ESP32 GPIO from ESD events, resets on inputs!

Tags: gpio, circuit-protection, esd, esp32, static

I'm working on a product that uses the ESP32 WROOM module.  There are 6 exposed pins that user can touch, shown by the header attached.  There is a piece of plastic that slides across a plastic housing, and makes contact with some metal contacts, to short some of the pins together to make a selection (binary math counts the number of on/off etc).  Anyhow, there is a static charge that builds up as the two plastic pieces slide, and as soon as the metal contacts touch, the ESP32 will brown out and reboot.  It's not software, it is for sure ESD (can wet the plastic and it stops).

I've tried researching the best I could, and this circuit does not seem to stop the reset sequence from occurring.  How can I stop this?  we do not have expensive ESD testing equipment, just an oscilloscope.

[image: ESP32 circuit ESD v1]

Comment: If your ground is getting nailed with ESD, this will upset your entire board.

Comment: Not shown is the direct path of +/- to cap to supply and ground on short twisted pair to power source cap not sharing paths used by electronics at right angles to other wires.  Change 1k to 10k and use TVS diodes. That’s a big Plastic RF cap. You can also spray antistat in between.

Comment: So exposed Ground maybe the biggest issue?   Can I protect it in some way? or can I replace it with exposed 3.3V rail?

Comment: also, note that the product is in a plastic enclosure, hand held device.  if that matters, I can't connect GND to the enclosure since it's non conductive, and cost sensitive.